# Problem with sidebar hiding after clicking outside it

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, addeventlistener, sidebar

For the past two weeks I have been struggling with the functionality that is supposed to hide the "sidebar" when you click outside the article list. Unfortunately this does not happen and only works when clicking on the icon.

left-menu.vue:

```vue
<template>
  <aside
    v-click-outside="onClickOutside"
    class="topnav left-menu p-3"
    id="myTopnav"
    :class="{ 'left-menu--show': showAside }"
  >
    <ul class="left-menu__list">
      <li class="left-menu__list__link"><a href="#">Article 1</a></li>
      <li class="left-menu__list__link"><a href="#">Article 2</a></li>
      <li class="left-menu__list__link"><a href="#">Article 3</a></li>
      <li class="left-menu__list__link"><a href="#">Article 4</a></li>
      <li class="left-menu__list__link"><a href="#">Article 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
</template>

<script>
import { mapMutations, mapState } from "vuex";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      active: false,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState("LeftMenu", ["showAside"]),
  },
  methods: {
    onClickOutside() {
      this.active = !this.active;
    },
    ...mapMutations("LeftMenu", { toggleShowAside: "toggleShowAside" }),
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.left-menu {
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: left;
}
.left-menu__list {
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.left-menu__list__link {
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.left-menu__list__link a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #b3bcc3;
  &:hover {
    color: #fff;
  }
}
.left-menu__toolbar {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.icon {
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .left-menu__list {
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 120px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 107px;
    left: -100%;
    background-color: #343a40;
    transition: 0.7s all;
  }
  .left-menu--show .left-menu__list {
    left: 0;
  }
  .left-menu__container {
    width: 20%;
  }
  .left-menu__toolbar .icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}
</style>
```

aside-toggles.vue:

```vue
<template>
  <aside class="aside__tooglers__container" :class="{ responsive: showAside }">
    <b-icon
      class="aside__left__icon d-lg-none"
      @click="toggleShowAside"
      icon="list"
      aria-hidden="true"
    ></b-icon>
    <b-icon
      class="aside__right__icon d-lg-none"
      @click="toggleShowRightAside"
      icon="three-dots"
      aria-hidden="true"
    ></b-icon>
  </aside>
</template>

<script>
import { mapMutations, mapState } from "vuex";

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState("LeftMenu", ["showAside"]),
    ...mapState("RightMenu", ["showAside"]),
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations("LeftMenu", { toggleShowAside: "toggleShowAside" }),
    ...mapMutations("RightMenu", { toggleShowRightAside: "toggleShowAside" }),
  },
};
</script>

<style>
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .aside__tooglers__container {
    padding: 15px 0;
    background: #343a40;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .aside__left__icon {
    padding-left: 32px;
    color: white;
  }
  .aside__right__icon {
    padding-right: 38px;
    color: white;
  }
}
</style>
```

left-menu.module.js:

```vue
export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        showAside: false
    },
    mutations: {
        toggleShowAside(state) {
            state.showAside = !state.showAside;
        },
    },
}
```

I tried using v-outside-click but it doesn't work.
Are there any other methods ?
Please help me with an explanation.

Comment: Please explain your code, not just paste it.  What is the purpose of your components state, data, different functions, etc? Explain the logic happening here.  What's important for what you're trying to do?  What's the actual strategy being implemented to hide the menu? Where do things appear to be going wrong? 
 I'm not even clear on how your two components are related.  There are apparently unused variables, like `this.active` which gets toggled but not actually used anywhere else.  What your code is doing vs what it should be doing is hard to deduce without your insight.